# Field set toggle on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a similar code to this. but I'd like to have the fieldset toggled when the page load. Also, show and hide when someone click on legend

```
<fieldset>
  <legend class="hide">Tags</legend>
  <div>
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="col" value="summary" 
       checked="checked" />
       Name
    </label>
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="col" value="lastname" />
     LastName
   </label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

JQuery

```
$(function(){
$('legend').click(function(){  
    $(this).nextAll('div').toggle();
    $(this).hasClass('hide')?($(this).attr("class", "show")): 
 ($(this).attr("class", "hide"));
  });
})
```

Comment: Isn't setting `style="display: none;"` as attribute for the `div` enough? Doing so will hide it on page load.

Comment: it worked thanks @Zim :)